# how to place the value of a string jquery variable as a hover text

Tags: jquery, string, hover, title

I have a string variable, str, that changes every time the user checks a box in a drop-down options menu. it contains all the values that are currently checked. I applied the text in the str variable to a div element like this:
the html:

```
                <div class="anchor" style="width:165px; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;" title= "">Everyone</div>
```

the jquery:

```
            $('.anchor').text(str);
```

this works. now, what i would like to do is to have the string in the variable str (which is the list of checked items) appear as hover text when i hover over the div. how can i go about that? doing title ="str" or title = str obviously doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the title as an attribute

```
$('.anchor').attr('title', str);
```